# Why does a rejected git push not show in 'git status'?

Tags: git

I am working on creating a pre-receive hook in git, and it's working as expected.

However, when the hook fails (i.e. validation failed within the script) the 'git push' is rejected as expected, and a relevant error message is given (error: failed to push some refs...) but 'git status' in the working directory does not show anything to indicate that the push failed.

If a developer did not notice that their push failed, they would not know from the output of 'git status' that there was anything wrong.

What command can I use to check if all my code has been pushed?

Comment: Well, _git status_ is for checking the status of local repo, and _git push_ is for working with remote repos. I'm not sure what the answer to your question is, but git is working as designed. It gave you an error message when you pushed, and then the status is correct _for the local repo_.

Comment: Besides @TriskalJM's comment, if you have your local branch set to "track" `origin/master`, `git status` will show a count of commits that you are ahead and/or behind your Git's remembered-value of the other Git's `master` (your `origin/master` is your Git's memory for this). To update your Git's memory, run `git fetch origin`, and then `git status` will give you an accurate (as of just now) count. Remember that by the time you run `git push` someone else might have pushed new contents, though, so you're always racing against everyone else who pushes. Whoever pushes fastest, wins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on the `master` branch, you could use the following command to check whether the state of your local `master` branch matches `master` in your remote repository:

```
git diff origin/master
```

If there's no difference the push must have worked. If some differing files are shown, the push didn't work or for some other reason (e.g. new uncommited local code) your local state doesn't match origin (i.e. your remote repo).

More generally use `git diff origin/MY_BRANCH` if you want to compare your branch with the name `MY_BRANCH`.